# How to create a readonly on the condition using html helper and using custom displayview in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

**1.** for example i have next helper and i need set status readonly (or disabled)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestTypeAdditional, new { @class = "form-control",   @autocomplete = "off" , **readonly = IsReadOnly(Model.IsClosed)**  })

@functions
{
    private static string IsReadOnly( bool isClosed)
    {
        if (RoleHelpers.IsInRoles("Master"))
            return "readonly";
        else if (RoleHelpers.IsInRoles("Operator") && (!isClosed))
            return string.Empty;
        else if (RoleHelpers.IsInRoles("Operator") && (isClosed))
            return "readonly";
        else if (RoleHelpers.IsInRoles("Administrator"))
            return string.Empty;
        else
            return "readonly";
    }
}
```

**2.**  i have custom view for model :-

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RequestType, new { **@readonly = IsReadOnly(Model.IsClosed)** })
```

works only  if the readonly (or disabled) explicitly specified or not. custom helpers not suitable

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you do this:

```
@if (IsReadOnly(Model.IsClosed))
{ 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestType, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) 
}
else 
{ 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RequestType) 
}
```

Comment: It will not affect your form. Finally you will have one control. If you have "readonly" attribute in your control, it'll be rendered as readonly textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try an brute force it. I agree you don't want your form code bloated with multiple repeating blocks.

I would recommend taking the code suggested by `Sergey Shabanov` above and placing it into display template. Then use a `UIHint` in our model to link to the display template. Presto, code complete with no bloat in your form code. You get to keep your `DisplayFor` and generally it resolves to a single line of UI code. Finally, you keep the implementation in a single location so changing it is not as error prone.

Answer (score 0):

I also think this could be one of the best ways to implement your strongly-typed TextBox custom helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>expression, bool isReadonly, bool isAutocomplete)
{
    MvcHtmlString html = default(MvcHtmlString);
    if (isReadonly)
    {
        html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, new { @class = "readOnly form-control", @autocomplete = isAutocomplete ? "on" : "off", @readonly = "read-only" });
    }
    else
    {
        html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, new { @class = "readOnly form-control", @autocomplete = isAutocomplete ? "on" : "off" });
    }

    return html;
}
```